# Какие фреймворки используются в среднестатистическом веб-сайте на Java

Tags: java

Много ли фреймворков надо знать? Какой стек технологий нужно знать, чтобы написать приличный сайт c богатым фронтэндом?

Answer (score 2):

Возьмите Spring+Hibernate(back-end) + Thymeleaf(frond-end), или сделать через Spring REST + Angular JS к примеру. 
http://spring.io/ - Spring
[link text](http://www.thymeleaf.org/) - Thymeleaf